# Integrating Spotbugs into Maven Pom - Won't generate a report?

Tags: maven, pom.xml, spotbugs

I am in the middle of trying to integrate the Maven Spotbugs plugin into my project's pom.xml file and make it so that it will generate a report in the "Project Reports" section after running the "mvn site" command. I am able to get other reports, such as PMD, CPD, and Xref to generate, but Spotbugs is given me a lot of trouble. The command line states that the report is successfully configuring, but never generating. I have what seems to be all the required dependencies, build, and report configurations. I've tried all kinds of solutions from the Spotbugs github site, the SpotBugs documentations, multiple forums and tutorials, and nothing seems to fix my problem.

Could anybody give me a very detailed step-by-step on how to incorporate the Spotbugs Maven plugin via the pom file? I am very new to Maven and could use some help! If I need to include any files, let me know that as well.

Comment: Can you share the snippet from your pom.xml and maybe the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved - spotbugs was requiring me to include all required configurations before it worked for some reason. I believe it worked after adding the following under the reporting section of the pom:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${spotbugs.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <effort>Max</effort>
                <threshold>Default</threshold>
                <spotbugsXmlOutput>true</spotbugsXmlOutput>
                <spotbugsXmlOutputDirectory>target/site</spotbugsXmlOutputDirectory>
                <skipEmptyReport>false</skipEmptyReport>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                <includeTests>true</includeTests>
                <classFilesDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</classFilesDirectory>
                <spotbugs.xmlOutput>true</spotbugs.xmlOutput>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>jp.skypencil.findbugs.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>bug-pattern</artifactId>
                        <version>1.4.0</version>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </configuration>
            <reportSets>
                <reportSet>
                    <reports>
                         <report>spotbugs</report>
                    </reports>
                </reportSet>
            </reportSets>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 6):

I followed the directions at [spotbugs.readthedocs.io](http://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/maven.html).  Add this section into project/build/plugins section of `pom.xml`.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
  <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.3</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
      <artifactId>spotbugs</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Then I ran `mvn spotbugs:spotbugs` and it generated `projectDir/target/spotbugsXml.xml`.  Then I ran `mvn spotbugs:check` and it output

```
[INFO] --- spotbugs-maven-plugin:3.1.3:check (default-cli) @ my-project ---
[INFO] BugInstance size is 0
[INFO] Error size is 0
[INFO] No errors/warnings found
[INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.731 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-05-25T16:31:35-04:00
[INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Update - I had to add it to the project/reporting/plugins section as well as the build section.  Now when I run `mvn site` it generates a `Project Reports` section in the `target/site/index.html` which includes SpotBugs.

```
<reporting>
  <plugins>
    <!-- SpotBugs -->
    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
      <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.3</version>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Comment: I appreciate the help! I tried the above already multiple times and it has not worked. I even tried starting over and followed your directions, but it's still not generating anything. Thank you anyways though

Comment: That did it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Stumbled over the same problem and the solution of @Mack did not work for me.

The final solution for me was to create the class files first.

So instead of

```
mvn site
```

at least a

```
mvn compile site
```

is needed to create the report.

Comment: Helped me as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party but following worked for me in december 2022:

```
mvn spotbugs:check
```